# SELECT from two tables with LIMIT 1 for second table

Tags: php, mysql, select

Hello everyone i have made simple search i take all columns by SHOW COLUMN and by whilei make a simple condition like THIS

```
while($columns = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)){
          if(!in_array($columns['Field'],$columns_a)){
             $columns_a[] = 'a.`'.$columns['Field'].'`'.' LIKE \'%'.$_POST['search'].'%\'';
          }                      
    }

while($columns2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
          if(!in_array($columns2['Field'],$columns_a2)){
             $columns_a2[] = 'b.`'.$columns2['Field'].'`'.' LIKE \'%'.$_POST['search'].'%\'';
          }                      
    }

$column_condition = implode(" OR ",columns_a);
$column_condition .= ' OR '.implode(" OR ",columns_a2);
```

So after this i have big condition to search. It works excelent and fast for my needs but there is problem and sql gives me two result if

```
$sql = mysql_query(
"SELECT * 
   FROM ".$prefix."orders a, ".$prefix."order_item b
   WHERE ".$column_condition." AND a.order_id = b.order_id 
   ORDER BY a.order_id DESC",$connect);
```

LIKE

first table - orders

```
order_id | name
1        | Chesus
2        | Johny
```

second table - order_item

```
order_id | order_item_id | product_name
1        | 999           | balsame
2        | 998           | better balsame
2        | 997           | worse_balsame
```

So if i search for Johny it gives me 2 result instead of 1

Comment: the question is, what do YOU WANT. Show us and example of what you desired result will be and we can then help. Do you want to show the data from both  row as 1? or do you want to show the entry with the largest/smallest `order_item_id`?

Comment: make habit of using mysqli_* instead of mysql_* as it deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

```
group by a.order_id
```

to your query before `order by`! :)

Comment: you deserve a medal :D

Comment: 2 more minutes its fresh :D

Answer (score 0):

Use a proper JOIN instead of an implicit join and you can then properly use the LIMIT syntax

Eg

```
$sql = mysql_query("
SELECT * 
FROM ".$prefix."orders a 
JOIN  ".$prefix."order_item b on (a.order_id = b.order_id)
WHERE 
".$column_condition." 
ORDER BY a.order_id DESC
LIMIT 0,1
",$connect);
```

Comment: your solution is good for my others functions but right now as guy bellow told me i only need a group by thank you anyway

Comment: sure, but be aware implicit joins are bad practice, you really should learn how to join tables in queries